# dapper.net, how to flush ConcurrentDictionary?

Tags: dapper, concurrentdictionary

I am new to dapper and plan to use it on my new project.  After reading it, seems like the only problem I might have is ConcurrentDictionary.

> Dapper caches information about every query it runs, this allow it to materialize objects 
>   quickly and process parameters quickly. The current implementation
>   caches this information in a ConcurrentDictionary object. The objects
>   it stores are never flushed. If you are generating SQL strings on the
>   fly without using parameters it is possible you will hit memory
>   issues. We may convert the dictionaries to an LRU Cache.

How do I avoid this problem?  Can someone please show me some code  tell me how and when to flush it?

Comment: So you are generating the SQL strings on-the-fly?

Comment: what does it mean by "generating the SQL strings on-the-fly"? can you give me an example.

Comment: The SQL string -- are you dynamically building it using a `StringBuilder`?  Or is it more of a constant string declared like `var sql = @"SELECT Foo FROM Bar"`?

Comment: I am not using stringbuilder, its slow. however I do use parameter in my query: Query<Thing>("select * from Thing where Name = @Name", new {Name = new DbString { Value = "abcde", IsFixedLength = true, Length = 10, IsAnsi = true });  does this consider as on-the-fly or not?

Comment: That's not on-the-fly and it looks good.  I suspect this is not the cause of your performance problem.  Can you elaborate more on the symptoms of the performance problem?  For example, does the same query perform much more quickly when run directy against the database server, for example? (via SQL Server Management Studio, or whatever)

Comment: kirk, Thank you so much. my application is fine.  dont really have any problems.  just want to find out if I am doing it right. Just to avoid doing it on the fly.  can you give me an example of on-the-fly?

Comment: I've added an answer in order to elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments up top, here's an example of on-the-fly:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("SELECT Foo FROM Bar");
if (fisrtName != null || lastName != null)
    builder.AppendLine("WHERE");
if (firstName != null)
    builder.AppendLine("    Bar.FirstName = @Firstname");
if (firstName != null && lastName != null)
    builder.Append(" AND");
if (lastName != null)
    builder.AppendLine("    Bar.LastName = @LastName");
var sql = builder.ToString();
```

As you can see, the actual SQL that dapper will now run will be different based on whether or not `firstName` and/or `lastName` are null.  If both are null, you get one SQL string.  If only `firstName` is not null, you get another.  If only `lastName` is not null, you get yet another.  And finally, if both are not null you get a fourth permutation.

This is what is meant by "on-the-fly" -- dapper will cache based on these unique permutations, and given a more complex scenario, it is easy to see how you'll end up with a great many different permutations, all of which would need to be cached independently.

Comment: sorry, one last question. the query I posted before, if I changed the value of the name. is it a new permutation?  is there a way to check if there are too many queries and need to flush ConcurrentDictionary ?

Comment: When you use the placeholders (such as `where Name = @Name`) then changing the value you pass in (such as `new {Name = new DbString { Value = "abcde", IsFixedLength = true, Length = 10, IsAnsi = true })`) is perfectly fine and is precisely how dapper is intended to be used.